# Find and replace URLs in a blob of text but exclude those in link tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace-callback

I have been trying to run through a string and find and replace URLs with a link, here what I have come up so far, and it does seem to work for the most part quite well, however there are a few things I'd like to polish. Also it might not be the best performing way of doing that.

I have read many threads on this here on SO, and although it helped a great deal, I still need to tie up the loose ends on it.

I am running through the string two times. The first time I am replacing bbtags with html tags; and the second time I am running through the string and replacing text urls with links:

```
$body_str = preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/i', '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">\2</a>', $body_str);

$body_str = preg_replace_callback(
    '!(?:^|[^"\'])(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?!',
    function ($matches) {
        return strpos(trim($matches[0]), 'thisone.com') == FALSE ?
        '<a href="' . ltrim($matches[0], " \t\n\r\0\x0B.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#'") . '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">' . ltrim($matches[0], "\t\n\r\0\x0B.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#'") . '</a>' :
        '<a href="' . ltrim($matches[0], " \t\n\r\0\x0B.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#'") . '">' . ltrim($matches[0], "\t\n\r\0\x0B.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#'") . '</a>';
    },
    $body_str
);
```

So far the few problems I am finding with this is it tends to pick up the character immediatelly before 'http' etc e.g. a space/comma/colon etc, which broke the links. Thus I used the preg_replace_callback to work around that and trim some unwanted characters that would break the link.

The other problem is that to avoid breaking links by matching urls, which are already in A-tags I am currently excluding urls starting with a quote,double-quote, and I'd rather use  href='|href=" for exclusion.

Any tips and advice will be much appreciated

Comment: can you please provide a sample text you want to feed to your function and the output text you need in result ?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

First i allowed myself to refactor a bit your code to make it easier to read and modify :

```
function urltrim($str) {
   return ltrim($str, " \t\n\r\0\x0B.,@?^=%&:/~\+#'");
}
function addlink($str,$nofollow=true) {
        return '<a href="' . urltrim($str) . '"'.($nofollow ? ' rel="nofollow" target="_blank"' : '').'>' . urltrim($str) . '</a>';
}
function checksite($str) {
        return strpos(trim($str), 'thisone.com') == FALSE ?  addlink($str) : addlink($str,false);
}

$body_str = preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/i', '\2', $body_str);

$body_str = preg_replace_callback(
    '!(?:^|[^"\'])(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?!',
       function ($matches) {
        return checksite($matches[0]);
    },

    $body_str
);
```

After that i changed the way you handle links :

- I considered that the URL is a word (= all characters until you find a space or \n or \t (=\s))
- I changed the matching method to match the existence of href= in the front of the string

  - if it exists then I don't do anything, it's already a link
  - if no href= is present, then i replace the link
- So the urltrim method is not useful anymore since I don't eat up the first char before http
- And of course, i use urlencode to encode the url and avoid html injection

```
function urltrim($str) {
    return $str;
}
function addlink($str,$nofollow=true) {
        $url = preg_replace("#(https?)%3A%2F%2F#","$1://",urlencode(urltrim($str)));
        return '<a href="' . $url . '"'.($nofollow ? ' rel="nofollow" target="_blank"' : '').'>' . urltrim($str) . '</a>';
}
function checksite($str) {
        return strpos(trim($str), 'thisone.com') == FALSE ?  addlink($str) : addlink($str,false);
}

$body_str = preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/i', '\2', $body_str);

$body_str = preg_replace_callback(
    '!(|href=)(["\']?)(https?://[^\s]+)!',
    function ($matches) {
        if ($matches[1]) {
            # If href= is present, dont do anything, return the original string
            return $matches[0];
        } else {
            # add the previous char (" or ') and the link
            return $matches[2].checksite($matches[3]);
        }
    },
    $body_str
);
```

I hope this can help you in your project.
Tell us if it helped.

Bye.